# C# FontFamily not showing new fonts

Tags: c#, windows, fonts, custom-controls

I notice that when we are trying to list fonts using C#, that it works fine; however, if we are to install a new font while the application is running, calling the enumeration of fonts doesn't return the new font, until the application is restarted.

Here's the code:

```
public void Populate(bool b)
{
    both = b;
    foreach (FontFamily ff in FontFamily.Families)
    {
        if(ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
            Items.Add(ff.Name);                                             
    }           
}
```

Notes for the above method:
`Items.Add()` is adding items to a `comboBox`.

I must be understanding something incorrectly here.  How can i get the above code to requery the system for the fonts, even the new ones?

Comment: did you try to recall your Populate method after installing new font in your machine? because the problem is, the application is already running and populating fonts is already done before you installed new fonts. Make something refresh button to refresh the list of fonts on your combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
foreach (FontFamily ff in fonts.Families)
{
    if (ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
        Items.Add(ff.Name);
}
```

Comment: so something like `var installed = new InstalledFontCollection();            foreach (FontFamily ff in installed.Families)` should do it.  i'll give it a try, ty for the direction.

Comment: That doesn't quite look right.  You aren't using the fonts variable.

Comment: LarsTech, I fixed it for @Marco. Just a simple typo.

Comment: It did not work unfortunately; We opened the program, it ran `populate` w/o issue, and we added a new font via windows (right clicked on it -> install) and then ran populate again, and it did not detect it.  We restarted the app, and it detected fine.  Still same issue, it's like it wont detect if until app is restarted.

Comment: @zackrspv: it's an old [discussion](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/fontfamily-collection-refresh-question-t2469694.html), but according to this it's a OS problem. Maybe they didn't fix it yet?

Comment: Ah man, that bites, but makes sense.  i think i'll post on MSDN and see if the issue is still a known bug for Windows 7.  Thanks Marco for the point on that, and u get the answer :)

Comment: @zackrspv: Thanks, I'm really interested in that!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Populate(bool b)
{
    both = b;
    InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
    foreach (FontFamily ff in fonts.Families)
    {
        if (ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
            Items.Add(ff.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Uhm, it seems perfectly equal to my answer ;)