# setting SelectionFont c#

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox

I am trying to make an advanced text editor in c#.
I currently have a toolStripComboBox populated with font names. When the user clicks on the name, it is supposed to set the SelectionFont to that font. However, it appears to have no effect.  (I also have one for font size, it works perfectly)

Here is the code for the application of the font:

```
private void toolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Font nf = new Font(toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(), getCntDocument.SelectionFont.Size, getCurrentDocument.SelectionFont.Style);
    getCurrentDocument.SelectionFont = nf;
}
```

The fonts are added to the box directly from the InstalledFontFamilies system class:

```
private void getFontCollection()
{
    InstalledFontCollection ifonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
    foreach (FontFamily ff in ifonts.Families)
    {
        toolStripComboBox1.Items.Add(ff.Name);
    }
    toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Also, getCurrentDocument is the following:

```
private RichTextBox getCurrentDocument
{
    get
    {
        return (RichTextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["Body"];
    }
}
```

> Additional Info:

```
private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); 
   string filePath = args[1]; 
   filePath.Replace("\\\\", "\\"); 
   addTab(); 
   getFontCollection(); 
   setFontSizes(); 
   getCurrentDocument.Text = (File.ReadAllText(filePath)); 
}
```

I get an `unsupportedFormatException`

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# FontFamily not showing new fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910490/c-sharp-fontfamily-not-showing-new-fonts)

Comment: @MethodMan no because that doesn't explain why this isn't working, its showing how to add them to the list... I already have them in a list

Comment: What is `getCntDocument`? Anyway, maybe try with the sample first https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont#Anchor_2

Comment: @MethodMan  One other thing: I appear to have a problem when loading files from a filepath (cmd args) I have this: `private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            string filePath = args[1];
            filePath.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
            addTab();
            getFontCollection();
            setFontSizes();
            getCurrentDocument.Text = (File.ReadAllText(filePath));

        }` I get an unsupportedFormatException. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found my answer, turns out I wasn't getting the text the proper way...
Instead of using`toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()`, I had to first use the `ToolStripComboBox.ComboBox`variable to convert the ts combobox to a regular combobox. This way I could use `toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.GetItemText(toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedItem)`

Thanks for everyone's help!